# WEB API in .NET Core 2.0.6 is slower than .NET 4.5.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've made a simple test to compare performance of ASP.NET WEB API with .Net Framewrok 4.5.2 and with dotNet Core 2.0.6 
Just runned locally, on my PC.

I've created a new project with framework 4.5.2, with the default "valuesController". There's nothing else in my project (no DBs, no other controllers)
[(Screen capture of VS with .net 4.5.2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv3an.jpg)
Then I run a simple load test with WebSurge to GET the IEnumerable (30 seconds, 8 threads) [(Screen capture of WebSurge results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGRsx.jpg).
As you can see, I get 11.326 total requests and 377 reqs/second

So, I did the same but with dotNet Core....just the default "ValuesController" [(Screen capture of VS with dotnet Core 2.0.6)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jabDg.jpg)
Then I run the same load test and I get this: [(Screen capture of WebSurge results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9z1z.jpg).
I get only 455 total requests and 15 reqs/second

Can someone explain me why this is happening? Am I missing something here?

**Edit**

I run in Release mode. For the .Net 4.5.2 project I get 72.763 requests and 2.425 reqs/second [image: 4.5.2 Image]. For the dotNet Core project I get 47.195 requests and 1.537 reqs/second [image: Core Image]

**Edit 2:**

As @fknx said, the debugger in dotNet Core is significantly slower than the debugger of the full .NET Framework.
I published both solutions, definitely dotnet Core is much faster! [image: WebSurge testing the published dotnet Core project]

Comment: Taking times using the debug configuration is probably not that meaningful.

Comment: Yes....sure...you are right, but both are in debug mode. Why there's so much difference?

Comment: On your screenshots it looks as if you ran your tests with an attached debugger. In my experience the .NET Core debugger is significantly slower than the debugger of the full .NET Framework. I'd guess that your results will be totally different if you re-run your tests without an attached debugger.

Comment: I run both versions in Release mode. For the dotNet Core solution I get 417 requests and 13.9 reqs/second. For the .Net 4.5.2 I get 10.416 requests and 347 reqs/second.

Comment: @GonzaloDiaz Did you start your projects [with our without debugging](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/11/01/start-debugging-vs-start-without-debugging/) (F5 vs CTRL + F5)?

Comment: @fknx Hi! there you can see the results in release mode.

Comment: @GonzaloDiaz This doesn't answer my question :-) A debugger can also be attached if you've compiled in release mode.

Comment: @fknx Sorry...my bad...I run without debugging (CTRL+F5) and the results are much higher, but still the API in 4.5.2 is faster than the API in Core

Comment: @GonzaloDiaz These new values look a lot better. One remaining difference could be that IIS Express runs as 32-bit application while the .NET Core app probably runs as 64-bit. You can switch to the 64-bit version of IIS Express in the [options](https://ppolyzos.com/2015/12/01/enable-x64-bit-version-of-iis-express/). Additionally, you could try to publish your .NET Core app and run it manually as described [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SpeedOfDotnetRunVsTheSpeedOfDotnetForPublishedAppsPlusSelfcontainedNETCoreApps.aspx).

Comment: @fknx That's the reason! When you publish both solutions, definitely dotnet Core is much faster! As you said previously, the debugger in dotNet Core is significantly slower than the debugger of the full .NET Framework. Thanks !